# modifying matplotlib's scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I have managed to produce a scatter plot which has a scale 1:1 using the command `plt.axis('equal')`, but the output contains too much white space on the sides. I have been looking for a way to remove that white space, such that the figure is more rectangular, but I haven't succeeded yet. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


E = [892.255, 837.587, 1227.914, 1212.741, 1053.381]
N = [395.173, 828.072, 662.757, 115.177, 519.491]
Labels = ['J1', 'J3', 'J5', 'C']

plt.scatter(E,N)
plt.annotate('J1', xy=(E[0] - 15, N[0] + 15))
plt.annotate('J3', xy=(E[1] + 10, N[1] + 5))
plt.annotate('J5', xy=(E[2] + 10, N[2] + 5))
plt.annotate('C', xy=(E[3] + 5, N[3] + 5))
plt.annotate('V1', xy=(E[4] + 15, N[4] - 20))
plt.annotate('V2', xy=(1015, 810))

plt.annotate('102,96', xy=(850, 540), size=8.5)
plt.annotate('29,99', xy=(965,655), size=8.5)
plt.annotate('65,13', xy=(1090, 640), size=8.5)
plt.annotate('119,83', xy=(1180, 500), size=8.5)
plt.annotate('82,09', xy=(980, 370), size=8.5)

plt.plot([E[0], E[4]], [N[0], N[4]], color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
plt.plot([E[1], E[4]], [N[1], N[4]], color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
plt.plot([E[2], E[4]], [N[2], N[4]], color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
plt.plot([E[3], E[4]], [N[3], N[4]], color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
plt.plot([1011.591064, E[4]], [817.704131, N[4]], color='k', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
plt.scatter(E[4],N[4], s=6500,facecolors='none',  color='k')


plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('E (m)')
plt.ylabel('N (m)')
#plt.ylim((100,900))
#plt.xlim((800,1250))
plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis([800, 1250, 100, 900])
plt.show()
```

Which produces:

[image: output]

Which is great, but it would be better if the x axis goes from 800 to 1300. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you just want to set the "adjustable" parameter to `"box"` instead of the default `"datalim"`.

Just add a line something similar to `plt.gca().set(adjustable='box')` near the end of your code.

Using your code above, this change yields:

[image]

(I also changed the x-axis limits to 800-1300 instead of 800-1250 to avoid some of the text hanging over the edge and the auto-placed ticks from being too dense.)